# Ajax CalendarExtender rendering badly on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I recently moved a .NET 3.5 application from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 R2. Everything looks fine except for the AJAX CalendarExtender. It appears far to the right of the associated textbox, and the background and font colors are gone. When I used a CSS class, I got the font to change color, but not the background. I've added an UpdatePanel, but that did not help.

Is there a setting in IIS that needs to be changed? Or something else I need to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue:

The problem was not the server, it was the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. The application had been using the 3.0 version, and needed the 3.5 version. The application itself had been upgraded to .NET 3.5 in 2013.

I exchanged the dlls, and everything is working.

Sara